# Network request fails

Tags: xcode, swift, networking

I'm just getting started swift, and I'm trying to make a post request like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var btnLogin: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func btnSignIn(sender: AnyObject) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://temp.com/api/v1/login")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {print(error); return}

            let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(result)

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

When I start my simulator in Xcode it's shows `build succeeded` and then it crashes on the following:

```
class AppDelegate:
```

message:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

What am I doing wrong? When I test this in playground it works!

Comment: Have you connected all your IBOutlets?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its crashing in the AppDelegate, without seeing the code in there I wouldn't be able to accurately tell you what the issue is.

If you remove the code in the `btnSignIn` method does it still crash?

I usually handle my POST requests like so:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// fill the request body, my API accepts JSON params
if let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: .PrettyPrinted) {
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData
} else {
    print("error sending params as JSON, params: \(parameters)")
}

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
    self.handleResponse(request, data: data, response: response, error: error, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

task.resume()
```